# mysql update based on select result, How combine?

Tags: mysql, select, update

Here are two SQL statements. One is an select statement and the other is a update statement. I want to combine them.

**Select**

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE `id`='1'
```

**Update**

```
UPDATE test SET `select_count`=`select_count`+'1' WHERE `id`='1'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the need to combine.  Perhaps you are getting all the columns (`*`)?  Or you don't like to issue two commands?  Or something else?

Comment: very often this bundle is used and I thought it might be possible to increase the productivity

Comment: Will you be performing those two commands more than a thousand times per second?  If not, then don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I think you need to include `SELECT` statement in `UPDATE statement`:

Sample SQL in below:

```
create table test1
(ID int,
select_count int,
select_name varchar(50))

Insert into test1 values (1,1,'A')
Insert into test1 values (2,2,'B')

UPDATE test1
SET select_count = select_count + 1 
where select_count = (SELECT select_count FROM test1 WHERE select_name = 'A')
```

Another way:  If you have 2 tables (TableA and TableB)

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.value = (
    SELECT TableA.value 
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name
)
where TableB.value < X;
```

Comment: These seem incomplete.  What is the set of columns indicated by `*`?